# Close browser/redirect when GWT service was called

Tags: java, gwt, service

Could someone please explain me what is happening when I call GWT service and before service returns response I close browser or redirect to another page?
ps. As I know the onFailure method of the service call's callback is called..
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev mode emulates the app behavior, so it may be different from the production environment. Most likely this onFailure() comes from your GWT plugin, because you tried to launch an app while the "previous" app was waiting for a callback.

When you refresh the app page in production, the browser closes all open connections that the page had. So your server will not be able to send any response - successful or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I believe nothing will happen. The JavaScript callback will be destroyed when the page is closed. This means the response will effectively be ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same. But in debug-mode, when I refresh page while RPC is in progress, the callback's method onFailure() is called with Throwable object with statusCode = 0...

Comment: Are you sure it's the same callback?

Comment: @Andrei Volgin no, I'm not sure...could you please explain what did you mean? Thanks

Comment: @ja6a - You are right about the production environment, but there is no JavaScript in the Dev mode. So the behavior might be different.